# Regex doesn't match, but only in Java

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have a problem with the following regular expression.
I have this string that I want to match

```
String test = "Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://an.url.example";
```

I want to "extract" the error code from this string using this regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\s([\\d]{3})\\s.*");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

But when I run this code I always get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.checkMatch(Matcher.java:1852)
at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:687)...
```

Then I thought my regex was wrong and I tested it on a [website](https://regex101.com/) .

[Picture of the regex matching the HTTP-response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPdJF.png)

Now I am even more confused and I really don't know what I did wrong (Maybe the method calls?).
I just hope someone can help me and clear up my confusion.
Have a great day!

Comment: You need to call find() on the matcher. The Matcher is stateful and it's initial state is "hasn't run yet". You can also call `matches()`, [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-matcher-find-vs-matches)'s an explanation about the difference.

Comment: you should have completed the [tour] - it states "Don't ask about... * Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for" - searching for `[regex] [java] IllegalStateException` must return [some similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bregex%5D+%5Bjava%5D+IllegalStateException)

Comment: I don't see any error in your code snippets. I guess the problem is somewhere else, i.e. in code that you haven't posted.

Comment: @MariánPetráš there is definitively one error: the `Matcher` requires calling `matches()`, `lookingAt()`, or `find()` (at least once) before calling `group()` or similar methods. Have you tested the snippet?

Comment: @user85421 Yes, I have tested the snippet. But I made a "mistake" by not copy-pasting the code. I rather looked at the posted code. When I was writing the code to JShell, I apparently fixed the missing call of Matcher.matches() unintentionally. :-]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API of matcher works like this:

You create your matcher, then you need to call a method to actually run it. The idea is that you can write something like this:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
  int number = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
  System.out.println("Found a number: " + number);
}
```

In your case, you just care about a single find. Hence, you probably want `if`, not `while`, here:

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
if (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
} else {
  // What do you want to do if 'test' does not contain this string?
}
```

Note that your regexp is overcomplicated. All you need is `Pattern.compile(" (\\d{3}) ")` - `\\s` is if you want to catch other whitespace such as tabs, but that's clearly not in your input, and there's no need to put `[]` around `\\d`. Technically just `\\d{3}` will do it, but, that'll find multiple matches in a number longer than 3 digits. A cleaner take is perhaps simply `"\\b\\d{3}\\b"`, taking the whole thing as a match (so, `.group(0)`) - `\\b` means 'word break' and doesn't capture any characters at all, it simply matches in the 'space between' - start of string, end of string, space, tab, that sort of thing marks a 'word break'.

`find()` just finds the first match. There's also `matches()` which is like find(), except it checks if the entire input matches. With your `.*` bounds it will, but `find()` and leaving the `.*` out is a lot simpler.

Comment: Side note: since Java 9, you can use `int number = Integer.parseInt(string, matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 10);` avoiding expensive `substring` creation (or use `matcher.start(1)` and `matcher.end(1)` to refer to `group(1)` but I’d follow your recommendation to simplify the regex to `"\\b\\d{3}\\b"`).